# What is the difference between windows and mac commands?

Tags: java, terminal, command, liquibase

~cd and ~ls -la "databaseName " how to write these commands ind windows? (this commands is for terminal)

i cant find mac and windows command

Answer (score 0):

these commands come with linux and mac, for use the commands in win is necessary install one "terminal for win", one example is the git bash

https://git-scm.com/download/win

sorry for English

Comment: i recommend you forget the win for programing, linux or mac are greats options

Answer (score 0):

**Linux and Mac** is based on UNIX which makes most terminal commands the same. Some are different based on terminal or OS. 
**Window** is based on Windows NT kernel which is an entire different family tree. That's why their commands is nothing like Linux. 
If you're going to use terminal a lot, consider using [**GitBash**](https://git-scm.com/downloads) or install a [**Windows Subsystem for Linux**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) for your machine. Therefore, you can stick with linux's command, which in my opinion is easier and less complicated than window's commands.